# TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): fields,model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, ldap

I am trying to show LDAP-attributes of a user by using the django-ldapdb library. First of all I made a new model:

models.py

```
class LdapUser(ldapdb.models.Model):
    base_dn = u"CN=XXX,CN=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"
    object_classes = ['posixAccount', 'shadowAccount', 'inetOrgPerson']

    # inetOrgPerson
    phone = CharField(db_column='telephoneNumber', blank=True)
    mobile_phone = CharField(db_column='mobile', blank=True)
```

I want to display these in my webapp with forms.

```
class LdapUserForm(ldapdb.models.Model):
    class Meta:
       model = LdapUser
       fields = (
       'phone',
       'mobile_phone'
       )
```

I did all my migrations and but when I run my code it gives me the following error.

> raise TypeError("'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): %s" %
>   ','.join(meta_attrs.keys()))
>   TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): fields,model

I looked it up but could not find anything helpful. So I hope someone on stacko has a solution for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Your form is inheriting from a model. It should be inheriting from `forms.ModelForm`.

Comment: Thank you again Mr. Roseman. Do you know how I can display these LDAP-attributes now. I do not really know how the django-ldapdb works. Maybe you know how I can built a view function with ldap-attributes?